# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, python-2.7

The declaration of the variable used is as follows:

```
self.features = {}      #dictionary defined for storing the features and the values
self.featureNameList = []  #list to store the names and values of the features
self.featureCounts = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1) #the counts of the features and labels
self.featureVectors = [] # 
self.labelCounts = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)            
def Classify(self):      #featureVector is a simple list like the ones that we use to train
    probabilityPerLabel = {}
    for label in self.labelCounts.keys():
        Prob = 0
        for featureValue in self.featureVectors:
            #print self.labelCounts[label]
            Prob+=self.featureCounts[[label][self.featureNameList[self.featureVectors.index(featureValue)]][featureValue]]/self.labelCounts[label]
            # Prob+= self.featureCounts(label, self.featureNameList[self.featureVectors.index(featureValue)], featureValue)/self.labelCounts[label]
        probabilityPerLabel[label] = (self.labelCounts[label]/sum(self.labelCounts.values())) * (Prob)
    print probabilityPerLabel
    return max(probabilityPerLabel, key = lambda classLabel: probabilityPerLabel[classLabel])
```

The error is produced on the line:

```
Prob+=self.featureCounts[[label][self.featureNameList[self.featureVectors.index(featureValue)]][featureValue]]/self.labelCounts[label]
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: Prob+=self.featureCounts[[label][self.featureNameList[self.featureVectors.index(featureValue)]][featureValue]]/self.labelCounts[label]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably:

```
[label][self.featureNameList[self.featureVectors.index(featureValue)]
```

What it looks like to me is that you are making a list of length 1:

```
[label]
```

And then you're trying to get an element from it via indexing:

```
[self.featureNameList[self.featureVectors.index(featureValue)]
```

But the stuff inside the outer brackets evaluates to a string.  And strings can't be used to index lists.

Ultimately, this is almost certainly *not* what you were trying to do, but I think it explains the error.  In general, I would recommend that you avoid really long and confusing 1-liners like that and break it up into it's constituent parts using temporary (but aptly named) variables.  This will make your code easier to understand and therefore it will be easier to write and develop.

Comment: Could you tell me how can fetch the value from the dictionary? If this is not possible?

Comment: @Soham -- Of course it's possible, but I have no good way of knowing *which* value you're trying to fetch.  Try following my advice and hopefully you'll be able to unravel your data-structure.